# Getting the name of the dataframe in a list for y lab in Boxplot

Tags: r, lapply, boxplot

The run down of my issue is that I have 20 dataframes. They are dataframes with 16 columns (which are dates q12007 to q42011) and 250 rows (which are companies) with each dataframes being for a separate variable (profit, revenue etc). I want to create a separate boxplots for each dataframe where the x axis is the date and the y axis is the value for the dataframe. An example of one is below (noting not of the dummy data but of thw actual data)

[image: boxplot example]

I can easily achieve the result I want with the following code

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(180),  ncol= 9))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(180),  ncol= 9))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(180),  ncol= 9))

man <- list (df1, df2, df3)
names(man) <- LETTERS[1:3] 

lapply(man,  function (x )   {
boxplot(x ,  las = 2 )})
```

However, I want to get the name of the dataframe and add it to ylab or the main title so I can tell what the plot is for. I know I can get the name of the dataframe that is in the list through

```
names(man)[1]
[1] "A"
```

But if I try something like this

```
lapply(seq_along(man), 
   function(x,y){ boxplot(x , names(x)[y], las = 2 )})
```

I get a disaster. I have tried a few other things but can not crack the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to `seq_along` was the right direction

```
lapply(seq_along(man),  function (x) {
  boxplot(man[[x]], las = 2)
  title(main = paste("data", names(man[x])))
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot also got this to work `lapply(seq_along(man), 
       function(i,x){ 
         temp <- names(x)[i]
         boxplot(x[[i]] , main = temp , las = 2 ) },
      x=man)`